# Unable to solve MyBatisSystemException

Tags: java, database, ibatis

I am writing this query in myibatis for updating postcode values

```
final String UPDATE ="update table_addresses "
                            + "set postcode= #{postCode}"
                            + "where id in = #{addressId}";
```

Here addressId is list.what is the syntax to pass List of addressId's here.

Currently I am getting this error:

```
Caused by: org.mybatis.spring.MyBatisSystemException: nested exception is org.apache.ibatis.type.TypeException: 
           Could not set parameters for mapping: ParameterMapping{property='addressId', mode=IN, javaType=class java.lang.Object, jdbcType=null, numericScale=null, resultMapId='null', jdbcTypeName='null', expression='null'}. 
Cause: org.apache.ibatis.type.TypeException: Error setting non null for parameter #2 with JdbcType null . Try setting a different JdbcType for this parameter or a different configuration property. 
Cause: org.apache.ibatis.type.TypeException: Error setting non null for parameter #2 with JdbcType null . Try setting a different JdbcType for this parameter or a different configuration property. 
Cause: java.sql.SQLException: Invalid column type
```

Answer (score 1):

According to standard SQL, an inclusion condition should have this format:

```
SELECT ... FROM ... WHERE id IN (#{addressId})
```

Answer (score 1):

You are using `=` instead of `()` for `IN` .Update your where clause as 
`+ "where id in ( #{addressId} )";`

Answer (score 0):

Use below code:

```
final String UPDATE = "update table_addresses "
                      + "set postcode= #{postCode}"
                      + "where id in = #{addressId,jdbcType=ARRAY}";
```